# How to run Hive commands on hadoop using python

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, bigdata

all, I am trying to use Python to run Hive commands on the Hadoop Edge node. I went through all related questions on this website. But I still cannot solve it.

Currently, I can run hive after I ssh the server using terminal:

```
ssh user-admin@abc-hadoop-edge01.endor.lan
```

Then type `hive`, I am able to run hive commands.

However, I cannot run hive using python. I use `pyhs2`. My codes are as follows:

```
import pyhs2
conn = pyhs2.connect('abc-hadoop-edge01.endor.lan', port = 10000, user = 'user-admin', password = '125438a', database='default')
cursor = conn.cursor()

conn.close()
```

The error is: `TTransportException: TTranspo...:10000`

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this ?

BTW: I use Mac.

Comment: Can you post the entire error please?